# Testing Adobe Analytics Instrumentation with Python

Tags: python, selenium, packet-sniffers, adobe-analytics

I'm attempting to automate tests of Adobe Analytics (aka Omniture) instrumentation of a web app by implementing test scripts with the Selenium Python package.

If correctly instrumented, HTTP requests are made from the browser with certain expected query parameters. Is there a Python package that would allow me to capture those outgoing HTTP requests? Right now, we do it manually with the Chrome dev tools in the Network -> Images section.

This application is also available as a native app across nearly twenty other platforms (including Smart TVs and game consoles), and I'll need to perform similar tests across those. Although, unfortunately, I won't be able to automate the script, I'd still like to capture and store the HTTP calls. I'm currently using HTTPScoop to do this manually.

I'm most comfortable with Python, but if there's a simple way of doing this in another language, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently working on a similar task so I can share my experience and what I've learnt on the way (rather than give you the solution).

First you need to run a proxy on your machine (e.g. http://bmp.lightbody.net/). Then I needed to run manually a few commands ( https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#rest-api). Once the proxy was running I wrote a small script following example here https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium. Finally you simply loop over the har entries as captured on the proxy and check if an analytics request is present (you can check for URL params if needed).

I have this ready in form of a unit test for FF and Chrome (for a given URL). To be able to run this test on different devices/OS/platforms one would probably need to run the code through selenium remote webdriver https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver using service like https://www.browserstack.com/ in the cloud. I contacted them but they don't have any documentation ready but suggested I refer to online resources. That's where I am now.

Hope it helps