# Automatic the process of testing in web analytics

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-analytics, analytics, adobe-analytics

I am using Adobe Analytics (aka Omniture). I try to automate the testing process which I can see now in chrome from *Inspect Element* --> *Networks* --> in filter use b/ss to see the server call. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30509558/5042030) I found an idea but nothing more.

I want to run the tests without need to open manually a browser and save the result to a file txt locally.

I found some untested solutions:

- https://github.com/shermozle/beaconWatch
- https://github.com/bbyars/mountebank

The first one seems a promising solution, bat how can I test it locally? (I have the site which I want to test). Can anybody help me with the steps?

Comment: You could use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and write a script that'll crawl and parse out all the scripts. Or you could use a paid service such as [ObservePoint](http://www.observepoint.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tracking specific server calls and save results locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169246/tracking-specific-server-calls-and-save-results-locally)

Comment: @MisterPhilip thank you I removed. Is there any example with PhantomJs?

Comment: I can't give away the code that does exactly this (for obvious reasons) ,but [their netlog example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netlog.js) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I played with sometime back and I was trying this with Selenium and Digital pulse debugger. Basically you can trigger debugger after every  url and grab all the values or compare with expected value.

Comment: Is it possible to give me an example?

Comment: its been a while so I dont have snippets but let me and try and list the steps:

Comment: - load the page
- Open debugger using JavaScript
- take the window handle
- itrate and take the elements like props eVars and you can either veriry then and there or dump evrythng in text file and later compare

Hope this helps!